# How to make drop down inside a JQgrid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

As title above how to make a drop down inside a jqgrid with a value of AM and PM?. Please share in jsfiddle. Thanks.

Comment: You should describe more clear what you need. Do you mean inline editing (or cell editing), form editing, searching, ... Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Moreover if you ask other to provide a jsfiddle demo then it would be god if you prepare the demo which shows how you use jqGrid and ask other to **modify your demo** by including additional functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work for you.

```
jQuery('#grid').jqGrid({
    autowidth: true,
    autoheight: true,
    url : '',
    mtype : 'POST',
    colNames : [  'ID','State', 'Type'],
    colModel : [ {name : 'id',index : 'id',hidden:true,align:'center'},
                 {name : 'name',index :'name',width:200,
                                        sortable:true,
                                        align:'center',
                                        editable:true,
                                        cellEdit:true,
                                        edittype: 'select', 
                                        formatter: 'select',

                                        editoptions:{value: getAllOptions()}
                 },
                 {name : 'type',index : 'type'},
               ],
    rowNum : 10,
    sortname : 'name',
    viewrecords : true,
    gridview:true,
    pager : '#pager',
    sortorder : 'desc',
    caption : 'Setup',
    datatype : 'json'
});
function getAllOptions(){
  var timeZone = { '1': 'AM', '2': 'PM' };

 return timeZone;

}
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. I tried this kind of code before but no luck not working.

Comment: the above code is working with me. if there is an issue in your side, please paste your code as also mentioned by Oleg